# How to call function from button with parameters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm very new to Excel and quite confused atm, so please forgive any basic questions. I have a custom VBA function that works perfectly:

```vb
Public Function MissingSequence(Rng As Range) As String

Dim iCnt As Integer
65        'ASCI character for "A"

    Dim iNum As Integer
    For iNum = 100 To 110

        Dim sCheck As String
        sCheck = Chr(iCnt) & iNum

        If Rng.Find(sCheck, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

            Dim sMissingNumbers As String
            sMissingNumbers = sMissingNumbers & "," & sCheck

        End If

    Next

MissingSequence = Mid(sMissingNumbers, 2)

End Function
```

I'm currently calling this function from within a cell using `=MissingSequence(D4:D10)`. However, I want to move this function call to a button instead.

When I create a command button with the following code:

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

MissingSequence(D4:D10)

End Sub
```

... and then press the button, nothing happens. When debugging it in VBA, I get a **syntax error**.

When I try this...

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click(D4:D10)

MissingSequence

End Sub
```

... and click the button, again, nothing happens. When debugging it, I get the error ***Expected: list separator or )***.

I'm now at a complete loss as to how to get this function working using a button, and feel like I've tried everything I possibly could, so I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Aside from the syntax issue (see @cyboashu's answer), all you're doing is calling the function and throwing away the return value - did you mean to do something with that?

Comment: Sorry, the Debug.Print was a leftover line from a previous version. I tried calling the function without that from within a cell using `=MissingSequence(D1:D4)` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are trying to use a command of

```
MissingSequence(D4:D10)
```

`D4:D10` means nothing in that situation (it will actually be thinking `D4` and `D10` are variables, or functions/subroutines, and the `:` is a command separator), so you need to use the `Range` function to convert it to a range type.

It is also better to prefix any range with a reference to the sheet on which the range is located.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'As this is a function that is being called, you need to catch the response.
    'Failing to do so will cause the compiler to think that is a subroutine
    'being called, and the `()` will force the parameters to be passed as values. 
    Range("B1") = MissingSequence(Range("D4:D10"))

    '/ This should be preferred. Sheet1 is just the example name.
    Range("B1") = MissingSequence(Sheet1.Range("D4:D10"))    
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried both versions. They're missing an end bracket, but even when I add those, I get a `run-time error 424: Object required` error. For some reason, when I save it as should look the VBA editor automatically adds a space between `MissingSequence` and `Range` too - not sure whether related.

Comment: The line just added - the MissingSequence line.

Comment: The inserted space (I assume it is generating `MissingSequence (Range("D4:D10"))`) will be because you need to assign the answer to something.  (See Tim's comment)  You probably want something like `Range("B1") = MissingSequence(Range("D4:D10"))`.  And that will then also solve the Object Required error too.

Comment: Brilliant, working perfectly now. Thanks to you both. @YowE3K, if you'd like to make your comment an answer, I'll accept it, or otherwise I'll accept cyboashu's.

Comment: (The reason why you got the Object Required error is that the brackets around `(Range("D4:D10"))` in `MissingSequence (Range("D4:D10"))` was forcing the range to be converted to an array of the cells' values, which then didn't match the expected parameter of a `Range` object.)

Comment: @YowE3K, yes please add an answer, you resolved it more than I did. And I will delete mine.

Comment: Haha. One more question - as it is, the results print to K1, as defined by `Range("K1") = MissingSequence(Range("D4:D10"))`. Is there any simple way to make the script print to a column of cells as each value is generated (K1, K2, K3 K4... etc., as needed), without having to explicitly list every single cell?

Comment: just `Range("K1:K10") = MissingSequence(Range("D4:D10"))`??

Comment: @YowE3K this is embarrassing. :) I am usually  slightly better than this.  :) Logged in my PC now!!

Comment: Would Range("K1:K10") be the only way to do it? What if I wasn't sure how many cells I'd be using? Is there no way to do it without specifiying the cells explicitly?

Comment: @Hashim - I suggest you make that a separate question - to answer it properly will require changing your function to a subroutine (or, at least, it would be best if it was), and introducing a counter, and possibly passing a second range (for the result), etc.  It will clutter up this question too much if we try to answer here.

Comment: That's fair enough, I thought that might be the case, hence I wondered if there was a simple way to do it. Once again, thanks to both of you!

Comment: @hashim - it is relatively easy - just off-topic for this question.

Comment: @YowE3K, I have lost it with this post. Kindly,  Feel free to edit what ever you think is correct. :)

Comment: OK - give me a sec - you go have a lie down and a cup of tea to recuperate LOL

Comment: Hopefully I didn't destroy your answer too much - feel free to edit further if you want to.  (I promise I won't look at it anymore!  :D)